# How can I query all the folder and file meta data using Google Drive API Services in one time query?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

How can I query metadata of the folders and files using Google Drive API Services, in the one-time for all?

I am using this API com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev170-1.20.0
for my app.

```
 compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev170-1.20.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}

 public List<File> listFilesInApplicationDataFolder() throws Exception {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    Drive.Files.List request = null;
    try {
        request = mService.files().list();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new IOException(e);
    }

    request.setQ("'appfolder' in parents");

    do {
        try {
            FileList files = request.execute();

            result.addAll(files.getItems());
            request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
            request.setPageToken(null);
            throw new Exception(e);
        }

    } while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
            request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

    return result;
}
```

This method gets all the folder and files from the root folder. But how can I get all the files in the sub-folder, in the one-time query?

My Drive folder structure looks like this:

```
  appdata
--P_Folder_1
         --S_Folder_1
                 --File_1
                 --File_2
                 --File_3
         --S_Folder_2
               --File_1
               --File_2
               --File_3
        --S_Folder_3
                 --File_1
                 --File_2
                 --File_3
--P_Folder_2
         --S_Folder_1
                 --File_1
                 --File_2
                 --File_3
         --S_Folder_2
                 --File_1
                 --File_2
                 --File_3
        --S_Folder_3
                 --File_1
                 --File_2
                 --File_3
```

Please give suggestions or doc to reference. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753914/how-to-list-all-files-folders-subfolders-and-subfiles-of-a-google-drive-folder) can give you idea on how to achieve your problem.

You can call the [`DriveFolder.listChildren`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveFolder#public-methods) that can retrieve a collection of metadata for the direct children of the folder. The result will also include metadata for both files and folders. Here is also the complete [code example](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/).

For more information just check the documentation of the API and this SO questions.

- [Google Drive Android API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro)
- [get metadata of all files and folders in Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453350/get-metadata-of-all-files-and-folders-in-google-drive?rq=1)
- [How to get list of all folders and files from google drive in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136349/how-to-get-list-of-all-folders-and-files-from-google-drive-in-android?rq=1)

Comment: OK. I got it. I have to do multiple queries for my case. Am I right?
Thank you so much!!